# Collapse rows to frequency in Python

Tags: python, pandas

```
ID       Color       Size    Category  
1       Green       Large   High       
2       Red         Small   Low 
3       Green       Small   High      
4       Green       Small   Low       
5       Red         Large   High      
...      ...      ...      ...
```

I have a pandas data frame that is set up like this.

What I want is to collapse all rows with the same specifications into one row with a frequency like this:

```
Color    Size    Category   Frequency 
Green    Large   High       4
Green    Large   Low        5 
Green    Small   High       3 
Green    Small   Low        7
Red      Large   High       14
...      ...      ...
```

For example, in the whole data frame, there are 4 individuals with Green, Large, and High as their values.

How do I make this transition?

Comment: `df.groupby(['Color', 'Size', 'Category'])['ID'].nunique()`?

Answer (score 2):

Count distinct `ID` for each combination of 'Color', 'Size', and 'Category', and rename result to `Frequency`:

```
res = (df.groupby(['Color', 'Size', 'Category'], as_index=False)['ID']
         .nunique()
         .rename(columns={'ID': 'Frequency'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try `groupby` then [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html)

```py
out = df.groupby(['Color', 'Size', 'Category'], as_index=False).count().rename(columns={'ID': 'Frequency'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html):

```
output = df.set_index("ID").value_counts()
```